# Chrome address bar font just changed (OSX)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion

The font used by the address bar just changed and it's bugging me, wondering if anyone might know how to reset it.  I tried creating a new profile and it's the same.  My other copies of Chrome (Canary / normal) have the "normal" font.

[image]

Dev on the left (the "broken" one, canary on the right.

Comment: I've seen this myself after some Chrome update; I think it's an (accidental) version difference but I don't know the official answer.

Comment: This issue has been submitted to the chromium project - `https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=276946`

Answer (score 2):

According to the explanation in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239135), this is an intended change landed in Dev (and now Canary) channel.

To change it back:

1. Open `chrome://flags`.
2. Disable Instant Extended API.
3. Restart Chrome. Font in address bar is reverted back to system font again.